# Compilation error: casting

Tags: java

Can somebody explain me why the following piece of code fails to compile. The error is: "`Possible loss of precision.`" :

```
byte a = 50;
byte b = 40;
byte sum = (byte)a + b;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did right by identifying that a cast is required, but unfortunately you did not apply it to the right expression due to precedence of operators.

Consider the following snippet:

```
static void f(char ch) {
    System.out.println("f(char)");
}
static void f(int i) {
    System.out.println("f(int)");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char ch = 'X';
    f( (char)  ch + 1  ); // prints "f(int)"
    f( (char) (ch + 1) ); // prints "f(char)"
}
```

The cast has a higher precedence than the addition, which is why the snippet prints what it does. That is, the first call is equivalent to `f( ((char) ch) + 1 );`. The result of the addition is an `int`, which is why the `f(int)` overload is invoked.

The lesson here is that you should **always use parenthesis** unless you're doing a very simple cast. In general, always consider using parentheses to make the order of evaluation explicit, even if they're not necessary. They lead to a better, more readable code.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the cast has a higher precedence than the + operator. Your code does this:

```
byte a = 50;
byte b = 40;
byte sum = ((byte)a) + b;
System.out.println(sum);
```

The cast is redundant, since `a` is already a `byte`. You probably meant this:

```
byte a = 50;
byte b = 40;
byte sum = (byte) (a + b);
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: +1: This is the critical part; the cast isn't being applied to what the questioner probably thought it was.

Answer (score 3):

Because the two byte variables are operands to +, they are implicitly promoted to int. This is called Numeric Promotion. Because int is larger than byte, and the result of a + b yields int, casting to byte possibly chops off some bits, as int is larger than byte. Hence the "loss of precision"

Doc for implicit numeric promotion:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#170983

Doc for the size of types:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: From my perspective this is a little dumb. The programming language shouldn't take care of this kind of errors. But I understand the issue now. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about java compilers, but in most C compilers that would have just been a warning. Consider yourself fortunate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bytes are added using "int" arithmetic; thus the result is an int and must be cast back from int to byte, which leads to the possibility of truncation.